# Explain what script/web is in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

`exec bundle exec thin -p $PORT -e ${RACK_ENV:-development} start 2>&1`

That's what I have in my `script/web` . Can someone explain the individual pieces of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is trying to start `thin` with the help of `bundler`. Here anything that has $ is a user argument that comes from the command line. The port and the `RACK_ENV` are defined from the command. The `RACK_ENV` has a default value of development environment which means if no environment is provided then start thing using the development environment

And as far as the `2>&1` is concerned, `1` is stdout. `2` is stderr.

Here is one way to remember this construct (altough it is not entirely accurate): at first, `2>1` may look like a good way to redirect stderr to stdout. However, it will actually be interpreted as "redirect stderr to a file named 1". & indicates that what follows is a file descriptor and not a filename. So the construct becomes: `2>&1.`

Comment: why does is there a `-' before `-development`?

Comment: try `echo ${RACK_ENV:-development}` in the bash terminal, this returns `development` if the $RACK_ENV environment variable is not set, so this means that the value `development` after `:-` is being a default value.